# Mongodb Store document values and read values from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

I am new to Mongodb,

I have already installed Mongodb in my system. From cmd prompt i am able to insert, update, find the document.

My question is how to do operations from application. Is that possible from java script. 
if it is yes, then how?. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find and install a driver for the language you're considering to build your application.

This page has a comprehensive list : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/drivers/

If the language you're considering is client-side (in the web browser) javascript, however, it's not possible due to security restrictions. You have to pick a supported language from the list above.